# Перемножить числа

Tags: c++

Задача:

Эффективно посчитать произведение вводимых с клавиатуры целых чисел.

Мой код:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <functional>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <numeric>
 int main()
 {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),std::istream_iterator<int>(),1,std::multiplies) << std::endl;
 }
```

Не компилируется. В чём проблема?

Сообщение об ошибке:

> [Error] missing template arguments before ')' token

Comment: Вы уверены, что так будет _эффективно_? Что вы вкладываете в это понятие?

Comment: видимо нужно читать так "эффЕктно"

Comment: (Ну и традиционно — сообщение об ошибке вы разрешаете нам угадать?)

Comment: минимальное количество строк кода?

Comment: @VladD производительность, кол-во кода

Comment: ... и приз в игре "Угадай-ка!" присуждается мне!

Comment: Производительность скорее всего будет хуже (по крайней мере, не лучше), чем у ручного цикла с аккумулятором. Но это не важно, т. к. время вычисления на несколько порядков меньше времени чтения с консоли.

Comment: @VladD непонятно, почему хуже. Ведь если вычислять непосредственно после ввода, то лучше быть не может, а `multiplies` должна быть эффективно реализована

Comment: @ilya1124: Вы имеете в виду, _лучше_ быть не может, правильно? А если где-то у вас есть стоимость абстракции (например, компилятор не сможет заинлайнить лямбду), то будет _хуже_.

Comment: @ilya1124 Простое перемножение двух int (без применения всяких классов и т.п.) выполняется одной инструкцией процессора. Быстрее просто некуда. А применение всяких классов притащит за собой сотни ассемблерных инструкций

Comment: @VladD да; понятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправить то нужно самую малость, дифф приложить?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <functional>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <numeric>

 int main()
 {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), 1, std::multiplies<int>()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

diff, для тех, кто понимает:

```
  int main()
  {
- std::cout << std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),std::istream_iterator<int>(),1,std::multiplies) << std::endl;
+ std::cout << std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), 1, std::multiplies<int>()) << std::endl;
+ return 0;
  }
```

Comment: что такое дифф?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: ну приложите...

Comment: Зачем было пробелы вставлять? Чем синхроннее дифф, тем интереснее его скроллить ;)